# Print using for-loop

Tags: javascript

Trying to import the shape (Pattern 23) from Java (source https://www.topjavatutorial.com/java/java-programs/25-java-programs-printing-number-character-patterns/ and print it in console:

I only manged to print the left shape using:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    let shape = '';

    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        shape += '*';
    }
    console.log(shape);
}
```

Any ideas on how I should try to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: here's a hint, include ALL from top to bottom

Comment: @JaromandaX he's talking about the 1st column-like shape

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it, building off the code you wrote:

```
function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split( '' ).reverse( ).join( '' );
}

// Build first 8 characters of each line.
lines = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    lines.push('')

    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        lines[lines.length-1] += "*";
    }
    for (; j <= 8; j++) {
        lines[lines.length-1] += " ";
    }
}


// Append the vertical mirror to get the first 16 characters of each line.
lines_2 = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    lines_2.push(lines[i - 1] + lines[8-i]);
}

// Append the horizontal mirror to get the entire 32 characters of each line.
lines_3 = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    lines_3.push(lines_2[i-1] + reverseString(lines_2[i-1]));
}

// Output
for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    console.log(lines_3[i]);
}
```

Result:

```
*       ****************       *
**      *******  *******      **
***     ******    ******     ***
****    *****      *****    ****
*****   ****        ****   *****
******  ***          ***  ******
******* **            ** *******
*********              *********
```

This isn't necessarily the most concise way to do it. But I hope you can see how we can arrive here by building, one step at a time, on the partial solution you started with.

Answer (score 2):

One option is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let stars = "*".repeat(9 - i).padEnd(9, ' ');
  let leftSide = "*".repeat(i + 1).padEnd(8, ' ') + stars;
  let rightSide = leftSide.split("").reverse().join("");
  console.log(leftSide + rightSide);
}
```

Result:

```
*       ******************       *
**      ********  ********      **
***     *******    *******     ***
****    ******      ******    ****
*****   *****        *****   *****
******  ****          ****  ******
******* ***            *** *******
**********              **********
```

Note that the result is slightly different from your original shape. The middle section of this shape has 18 lines but the middle section of your shape has 17 lines.

Comment: Pretty solution.

Comment: Thanks Edper. This was an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a pure for-loop of `*` and spaces answer:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    let shape = '';

    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        shape += '*';
    }
    for (var j = 8; j > i; j--) {
        shape += ' ';
    }
    for (var j = 9; j >= i; j--) {
        shape += '*';
    }
    for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        shape += ' ';
    }
    for (var j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        shape += ' ';
    }
    for (var j = 9; j >= i; j--) {
        shape += '*';
    }
    for (var j = 8; j > i; j--) {
        shape += ' ';
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        shape += '*';
    }
    console.log(shape);
}
```